# How can I identify wild edible plants of southern and eastern China?

Tags: survival, food, foraging, resources

What wild edible plants can be found in southern and eastern China?

I have combed through various search queries but keep finding information on North American flora.

Are there any good resources available that would aid my research or is it a matter of (rather dangerous) experimentation?

Comment: I came here from Travel.SE, so I'm not an outdoors survival person, but I'm a native of the region. My advice is to avoid this experimentation; the subtropics are very abundant in poisonous plants. In Southern China, even seemingly harmless trees frequently seen along the streets might be quite poisonous when consumed. Also, soil pollution is another big problem; even if edible, the plants might contain high levels of heavy metals.

Comment: @xuq01 A fair point, I hadn't thought about the pollution. Are there people that eat the native plants, and how do they deal with it?

Comment: Locals tend to avoid them AFAIK

Comment: @xuq01 How do people source food?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Most people grow or buy their food. You don't expect most people to forage from the wild, do you?

Comment: @xuq01 No, but I meant if the ground is polluted wouldn't home-grown produce also be polluted? Or how does one deal with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89302/discussion-between-xuq01-and-a-lambent-eye).

Comment: The book *Grass Soup* has a description of the plants eaten by the starving residents of a Chinese prison camp. Long story short, they were so desperate they picked every green thing they could get their hands on and put it into the soup pot. If any of it was poisonous, it didn't really matter because they ate so little of it. I definitely *don't* recommend trying that, but it is an interesting account.